# Как парсить JSON и вывести результат на PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, decode

При выполнении следующего кода:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'X-Auth-Email: n*****y@gm***l.com';
    $headers[] = 'X-Auth-Key: 99c22da2f4b*******9b8';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Получаю ответ в JSON:

```
string(32263) "{"result":[{"id":"7ca47d86d0f56fe45ad01edb6c4c7771","name":"airbeautty.xyz","status":"active","paused":false,"type":"full","development_mode":0,"name_servers":["megan.ns.cloudflare.com","pete.ns.cloudflare.com"],"original_name_servers":["ns1.dns-parking.com","ns2.dns-parking.com"],"original_registrar":null,"original_dnshost":null,"modified_on":"2020-02-03T09:42:48.400052Z","created_on":"2020-01-21T16:08:27.427894Z","activated_on":"2020-01-21T20:45:26.569680Z","meta":{"step":4,"wildcard_proxiable":false,"custom_certificate_quota":0,"page_rule_quota":3,"phishing_detected":false,"multiple_railguns_allowed":false},"owner":{"id":"e83cce4c2dbf21dabfae3b934e5f38dc","type":"user","email":"nhmelevskiy@gmail.com"},"account":{"id":"765fc88c380e008cc8556461647b83ca","name":"nhmelevskiy@gmail.com"},"permissions":["#access:edit","#access:read","#analytics:read","#app:edit","#auditlogs:read","#billing:edit","#billing:read","#cache_purge:edit","#dns_records:edit","#dns_records:read","#lb:edit","#lb:read","#legal:edit","#legal:read","#logs:edit","#logs:read","#member:edit","#member:read","#organization:edit","#organization:read","#ssl:edit","#ssl:read","#stream:edit","#stream:read","#subscription:edit","#subscription:read","#waf:edit","#waf:read","#webhooks:edit","#webhooks:read","#worker:edit","#worker:read","#zone:edit","#zone:read","#zone_settings:edit","#zone_settings:read"],"plan":{"id":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Free Website","price":0,"currency":"USD","frequency":"","is_subscribed":true,"can_subscribe":false,"legacy_id":"free","legacy_discount":false,"externally_managed":false}},
    ?>
```

Как мне выводить только name (airbeautty.xyz) и id (7ca47d86d0f56fe45ad01edb6c4c7771) при учёте, что их может быть много и нужно вывести все?

Понимаю, что нужно декодировать JSON , но я не силен в этом, буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Откройте гугель и введите туда запрос "php декодировать json".

Comment: @u_mulder , если бы получилось самостоятельно - я бы не задавал вопрос здесь)

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true)['result'];
$data = array();

foreach($result as $item) {
    array_push($data, array(
        'id' => $item['id'],
         'name' => $item['name']
    ));
}

var_dump($data);
```

> Работа с массивами: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php
>
> Работа с JSON: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.json.php

Comment: выдает в результате теперь NULL

Comment: @IvanAndreevich, Изменил ответ... Я не увидел что там несколько значений... Это основы, почитайте информацию по ссылкам что я вам предоставил, тогда подобное сможете делать сами!

Comment: @IvanAndreevich, И вообще сделайте просто: $result[0]['id'];